# Как в скрывать кнопки внутри приложения?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Нужно изначально скрыть все кнопки внутри приложения, а когда игрок заходит — показывать кнопку.

Как например сами окна в pyqt5 `window.show/close`, только для кнопок.

Что в питоне поможет это сделать ? Какие события есть/можно организовать ?

Comment: Будет полезно для вас https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#visible-prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
your_button.show()
```

```
your_button.hide()
```